# Primefaces Datatable SelectOneMenu Render Problem

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a primefaces (8.02) datatable with editable rows (rowEditor/celleditor). A couple of the data-elements in each row are a drop-downs (selectOneMenu) with value & label.

My problem is when I click on the roweditor pencil and the row goes into edit-mode my drop-down columns only show the centered arrow (cursor) of the drop-down (selectOneMenu) element. No text at all. In the showcase for editable datatable the cursor is neatly tucked to the right and I can see both text and cursor.

Once I click on the cursor it presents me with the list of selectable elements. Then I choose one and the drop-down collapses as it should but again all I see is the (centered) cursor) not any of the selected text, not even partially. When I press roweditor-save I can see a value change has occurred in accordance to what I picked in the drop-down.

I'm not sure where to start. The exact same selectonemenu construct works fine outside the datatable. I'm thinking its probably more a style/render problem? What I aslo noticed is when I tab through the row and I land on the drop-down I cannot use cursor keys to go through the options. Only mouse works. Maybe just another symptom of the same problem.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks for you time

Carsten

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. And note that the showcase uses a `h:selectOneMenu` (not a `p:selectOneMenu`).

Comment: Thank you Jasper. Sorry about the missing code sample. I was hoping I could describe it adequatively in text. However your hint with regards to h:selectOneMenu was the thing that I just could not see. Thank you very much. That looks just like I want it now.